# Firebase: referencing docs with a string vs. referencing docs with a ref. Is there a difference?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This is more of a general question, I've been bouncing around multiple posts on StackOverflow and reading what I've found so far in the docs. I haven't found anything super concrete yet to answer the post question which is: **what are the benefits of linking documents to one another through the `ref` type vs. the `string` type?**

As of now, I'm converting all my *string "refs"* to properly typed "refs". However, since i'm still relatively new to the platform I'm scratching my head wondering if this is even necessary. I assume I'd be just as effective at finding related docs with the string as with a reference.

---

Also, for the sake of future readers as of me posting this, you can set a ref like so:

```
db.collection(...).add({
 ...
  reference: firebaseFirestore.doc(
    `lesson_translations/${translationID}`
  ),
  // reference is now typed as a 'ref'
})
```

I had found other posts on stackoverflow accessing it with `.doc(...).ref` which doesnt *seem* to be a thing anymore.

Comment: The firebase teams walks through the benefits here: https://youtu.be/Elg2zDVIcLo?t=276

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's mostly a matter of personal preference and perceived convenience.  There is not really anything a reference type can do that a string and your own code could not also do.

Having a reference type mostly saves you the trouble of building a new reference object in your code, if that's what you would have done with a string document ID anyway.  You can also use it in security rules for the same purpose when it comes time to use `get()` to fetch another document referenced by a field.

Again, it's personal preference. Do whatever is most convenient for you.

Answer (score 1):

When you call a document reference, you instantly get the document details while if you take a string path and call it, it will take some time to find that data. It is just a matter of a few milliseconds and a few lines of code. Imagine if you had a list of document references to store and you store them as strings, and then had to call all of them looping over it

Comment: The question isn't asking about "calling" a document reference.  It's asking about the practical difference between storing a string and storing a reference when referencing one document from another.

Comment: Yeah but I was talking about how you store it will affect him in the future calling it. In storing, its not much of a difference. Maybe there is a few bytes of difference but it does not matter a lot

Answer (score 0):

I know of one tangible benefit, but it's only relevant if you are using a library for data binding that supports loading nested documents to n depth. I personally am using [vuefire](https://vuefire.vuejs.org/), but I would assume something similar exists for the react ecosystem.

It allows you to e.g. bind a collection or document to a variable, and automatically sync all the data of referenced documents.

**Example**

You sync a `collection('users')` with a depth of two, and each user document contains an array of favourites:

```
{ 
  name:'John',
  favourites: [ref1, ref2, ref3]
}
```

The library would immediately download the references and replace the original ref files with the data:

```
{ 
  name:'John',
  favourites: [{title:'foo'}, {title:'bar', {title: 'baz'}]
}
```